# Checkbox state is opposite of boolean value?

Tags: php

I have the following code that should mark a checkbox as checked if the query returns `1` :

```
<?php
$isAdmin = (bool)$isAdmin; //1 = true, 0 = false
$checked = ($isAdmin) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="isAdmin" value="1" <?php echo $checked; ?> /></td>
</tr>
```

The problem is, when I open the form, if `isAdmin = 1`, the checkbox is unchecked, and if `isAdmin = 0`, it is checked.  It should be opposite.

I know I could simply swap

```
$checked = ($isAdmin) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
```

for this

```
$checked = ($isAdmin) ? '' : 'checked="checked"';
```

However, shouldn't this work as if true then else instead of if false then else?

Comment: Reverse it then: `$checked = ($isAdmin) ? '':'checked="checked"';`

Comment: add not operator `(!$isAdmin)`

Comment: Why, the current code is fine.Check if something else on page is causing this. echo `$isAdmin`  and see what it prints.

Comment: where does `$isAdmin` get assigned at, if the checkbox is unchecked it's not set in the `$_REQUEST`

Comment: your code works here - https://3v4l.org/mWEuj show how you are defining `$isAdmin` before this code block.

Comment: Try this at the top after before the `(bool)` casting `var_dump( $isAdmin );` see what kind of variable it is, and that it's value is what you think it is.

Comment: isAdmin is returned as 1

Comment: Weird.  Working everywhere else and updates/inserts correctly.  Just not displaying the right result on this one page.  guess I'll just swap, seeing it's only for initial display.  If checked and I uncheck it, update, it is reflected properly in the db.  Visa versa.

Comment: Then do `var_dump($checked )` after the ternary statement `{condition} ? true : false;` bit.

Comment: @MichaelM - you cant `Just Swap it` if its not working right, its a bug.  Obviously as the code works your input has to be wrong.

Comment: I know @ArtisticPhoenix.  Bugs just build up.  Had to take a few minutes to reset my eyes.  var_dumping after the temp statement.  will update in a sec

Comment: The point is that, what seems like a minor issue could unravel into a much bigger problem.  It's the pull the yarn syndrome.  Best bet is you are setting that variable out of the scope of the current script.

Comment: OK, figured it out.  My eyes didn't catch the order I was binding everything.  Had them reversed.  Looks like it's working now.  I need sleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code provided works when manually setting $isAdmin to 1, review what this value is set as to determine the issue.

Comment: You might want to explain how to "review that it is set" in some code.  Such as `$isAdmin = isset($_REQUEST['isAdmin']) ;`

Comment: True. I would **var_dump** isAdmin and view the results printed to the screen.

Comment: Most the time an error is not in the logic but in the input, there is only 3 kinds of errors,  Syntax, Data, Logic.

Comment: isAdmin is returning 1.  It's set in my db as TINYINT, and on a previous screen, where the value is dumped to a table, it's populating correctly.

Going line-by line now to see if there is something else.

Comment: That may be but you did do, var_dump, just before using it right.  If it's fine on another page doesn't matter because of scope.  We're no on the other page, so what that does is largely irrelevant, unless it executes before this and within the same request and scope..

Comment: the provided code is working fine when we set $isAdmin=1 or 0 manually...so 1st echo the $isAdmin value at he top & check if it is 1/0...

Comment: It was the way I was binding it.  Had it ordered improperly, so the value wasn't being returned to the proper var.